# Why is my RSS feed showing up on the bottom when I'm floating it to the right?

Tags: css, html, rss

Link: Neilson.webege.com/news.html

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tm9B8/

```
<html>
```

I am trying to get my RSS feed to appear floated right, about as high as the nav. Instead, it is below the Nav.

How do I fix this? I floated my RSS feed to the right and it still won't go.

Answer (score 0):

In my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tm9B8/1) the div got a test class with `position:relative and float:left`.